Is it possible to create a prefab/variant with a different gameobject hierarchy?
I have a model which has many different parts as children gameobjects. If I select the model in the project view I can change all of the materials (incl children) in the materials tab in the inspector, without needing to do so for every single child:

However, I need to rearrange the hierarchy of this model, since at present it is just a giant list of children gameobjects and I would like to add some additional children to act as categories/headings. The problem is I cannot change this hierarchy because:

If I unpack the prefab I can then change hierarchy, but I lose the ability to change the materials from the materials tab (since updating the original prefab materials now is ignored by this new one). So I am guessing if at any point I need to replace any material I would have to manually go through the entire hierarchy and change that material on each gameobject?
Is there not a better way to be able to change the hierarchy but also keep the ability to use the material tab?
